# Grafana XAMPP Mysql Timezone issues with SUM

Tags: datetime, timezone, grafana

```
SELECT 
    SUM(follow) AS 'FOLLOW',
    SUM(unfollow) AS 'UNFOLLOW',
    SUM(dm) AS 'DMs'
FROM 
    statistics.project_stats
WHERE 
    project_id = $projectName AND
    $__timeFilter(timestamp)
```

I store timestamp in UTC0, and in Grafana I set filter for UTC+2:00, and for yesterday stats, it count till 2:00 hour for today, so its not related to what I select, anyone know what Im doing wrong?

I want to filter and return values which are related to UTC2:00 of grafana and time period I select.